# Netstat -i redirection problem

Tags: bash, scripting, netstat

When I run this command `netstat -t 1 -i 2>&1 > $NETStat_OUT_FILE &` inside a  script , the output of netstat does not get redirected to the file.. Could any one find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect stdout first, then stderr.

```
netstat -t 1 -i > $NETStat_OUT_FILE 2>&1 &
```

Comment: sorry.. there is no problem as such..but when i try to read the output file immediately after execution it puts out a blank file.. the redirection program takes time to write the output onto the output file..i'm able to view the output if i open it after sometime

Comment: @Sharat: What is the time taken by command to give output if you are not redirecting it?

Comment: it is instantaneous ,if you are not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the timing problem you can use wait:

```
netstat ... &
p=$!
do something else ...
wait $p
```